# How to hide code from view source or ristrict to copy..?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to encrypt my HTML, PHP & JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784408/how-to-encrypt-my-html-php-javascript)
>   [How to disable or encrypt “View Source” for my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788539/how-to-disable-or-encrypt-view-source-for-my-site)

If we click to **View Page Source** option of browser then you can not only view the code but also copy and reuse as your need. But some time you don't like to forward your code without permission, so how can you hide your web page source code form users so that s/he could not copy your code without your permission.

I visited it a website

and if you view it's source code and paste on a web supported file (html, htm, php, etc) then you can not edit some of the text as well as you are not allowed to access some css.

Comment: The site you mentioned, has all css/js  and html totally accessible. Infact it quite well written with pretty line breaks (uncompressed)

Comment: Nice answer there @alex funny how I didn't find that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't restrict to copy or anything.

One option you have is to [Obfuscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscate) your source. Obfuscation basically compresses and/or renames variables, methods. It makes things a bit faster and the code gets a lot more difficult to understand.

See

- [PHP code to obfuscate HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600190/php-code-to-obfuscate-html)
- [Is there a code obfuscator for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)